# jqTouch back issue

Tags: jquery, jqtouch

I have this app that been working well but have had to update it recently, but I have noticed that my next page code seems to work OK, bu then my back page does not seems to want to go back.

I dont think its back thing as I am using the following coed for my next / prev links:

```
   <a id="prevs" class="previous slide reverse" href="#intro"></a>
   <a id="ntpg" class="next slide" href="#descpg"></a>
```

What i have also noticed is that when it first loads I have to buttons that basically say's Start and the other About.

When I press start it works but when i press about nothing happens.  The about page content is above the intro page so I moved it to below and it then worked.

So I began to see a pattern here, every time i goto the next page it wont go back because that page came before it and its as if its deleting the one before and thus there is nothing to actually go back to?

Any ideas would be great.

I am using the latest jquery and jqtouch js files.

ALSO:

I also have a swipe effect on the pages as this is the same i can go forward but when i swipe to go back it again does not show the page:

Swipe code is below:

```
  var $cp = $(this).closest('div>div').attr("id"), 
  $pp = $('#'+$cp+ ' #prevs').attr('href'), 
  $np = $('#'+$cp+ ' #ntpg').attr('href'),
  $dr=i.direction;
  if($dr=='right'){ jQT.goTo($pp,'slide', true); } else if($dr=='left'){jQT.goTo($np,'slide', false);}
```

In answer to a comment below the ids are used fro the above swipe code.
I have traced out the back swipe etc and it calls the page id but for the same reason it does not want to go back.

Comment: Why are the ids so inconsistent? `prevs` and `ntpg` each sound like a different convention. I'd go with `prev` and `next` or `pvpg` and `ntpg` though the former is more apparent.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems that when I was updating the content I missed out the latest jqtouch.css file, so I go this in and it worked.

The only issue now is the right swipe which still fails to work but this is another question.